# web passes the parameter including `\n` to iOS native method

Tags: javascript, ios

web passes the string parameter like this :

[image]

However, in my iOS native method, I receive the string :

[image]

'\n' ----> '/n'

I do not know why, hope someone give me some advices

Comment: I creat a frame in web, and the value of src is like "xxx\ncdcd". In native iOS , I use `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method to get the url

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by encoding the parameter:'encodeURI()'.